# Print the value if associated parent table in django

Tags: python, django

Working on django project, I have an Event table. Every event in this table belongs to a particular user.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    user_id=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_auth_id=models.CharField(null=True, max_length=225)
    event_auth_step2_id=models.CharField(null=True, max_length=225)
    event_title=models.CharField(max_length=225)
```

I am writing a query on Event model and using values() method to find values of specific columns, But i also wants to print that user's email id which is in User model. Query is:-

```
events = Event.objects.all().filter(**filters).values('id', 'event_title', 'category', 'event_start_from', 'event_start_to', 'created', 'modified', 'event_status')
```

How can i print the value of user's email which is in users table. also i want to add a filter to filter users by email id, but want to write query on Event model

Comment: You should be able to add `user_id__email` in the `.values()` call. Totally unrelated, you should rename `user_id` to `user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__` lookup syntax to access related model `'user_id__email'`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

```
events = Event.objects.all().filter(**filters).values('user_id__email', 'id', 'event_title', 'category', 'event_start_from', 'event_start_to', 'created', 'modified', 'event_status')
```

Also `user_id` your `_id` is redundant here. django will name this field `user_id` in DB by itself, when you use ForeignKey

**Answering comment**
Same idea for filter/exclude `.exclude(user_id__email='')` exlude all Events with user without email

```
events = Event.objects.all().filter(**filters).exclude(user_id__email='').values('user_id__email', 'id', 'event_title', 'category', 'event_start_from', 'event_start_to', 'created', 'modified', 'event_status')
```

Comment: working now thanks, and how can i add filter to search record with email.